# Cordova processMessage failed: Stack: undefined (and) Error: illegal access

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm trying to get this GCM regId via [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin).

I can't find any documentation per 'illegal access' error message... sounds almost like a permissions thing. The JS function onNotificationGCM pings a log message, indicating it's execution...

Error message:

```
processMessage failed: Stack: undefined
processMessage failed: Error: illegal access
processMessage failed: Message: Jjavascript:onNotificationGCM({\"regid\":\"APA91bGQkVTa6KGBQzNz9spnYgYEL6RSJKyyoNh5GnhrkD04wVgm1detXbuATLRC_Evjduv4NCPZWzw_Q-ilEl4U_XBjibiSHPgzWEoO0_VBqB6HT_TDNMsJoxoGZu1ZXyFZNDXQawCJxv5KcQiCp7zmbaICt9n4TQ\",\"event\":\"registered\"})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, go figure. It seems that I was attempting to parse a JS object with JSON.parse, which--a discovery also made via [this article](http://samritchie.net/2011/04/01/uncaught-illegal-access-exception-in-android-browser-on-json-parse/)--throws these 'Illegal access' errors. Once I made sure the passed in msg was a string before parsing JSON, the errors disappeared and regId was handled successfully. w00t.

Comment: Can you give an answer for this? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25967691/reference-error-onnotification-is-not-defined-in-push-notification-cordova-andro)

Comment: Make sure you're sending the right thing via gcm. It was a while ago when I had this problem, but at first glance it looks like I was trying to feed onNotificationGCM a JavaScript object rather than a JSON.stringify(..) version of the object.