# Process message failed in Javascript pushnotification

Tags: javascript, cordova, push-notification

I'm trying to get this GCM regId via (https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin). But I am getting the following error in logcat.

```
09-23 10:20:07.640: I/Web Console(31679): processMessage failed: Message: Jjavascript:onNotification({"regid":"APA91bHDLg9BZl-eicx3tS-MjVGy-mcufmbRc-EpCuKzb9b_tPddG125jyxY-OhVR5vul6az-eJ2nZ0PEiOVPqP2KjClaUwAKTBQx5gsIluI0jsGIrpCvNQdUbtKUBxNNH0DH94RHuGpjU29xhTS5Cl8qIgH1MlJHw","event":"registered"}) at file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:1046.
```

I refered to this question ([Cordova processMessage failed: Stack: undefined (and) Error: illegal access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220524/cordova-processmessage-failed-stack-undefined-and-error-illegal-access)), but can't find the answer.

Comment: window.onNotification = function(){} . Make sure onNotification have scope in window. If not solve, post your code.

Comment: Here is my actual question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25967691/reference-error-onnotification-is-not-defined-in-push-notification-cordova-andro)